# I need helping writing an excel vba Splat function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm using Excel 2007 and need some assistance / guidance on how to write a Splat user defined function function.  The Splat function enables you to input data into a cell that contains a vlookup function and then update the look-up table with the value you entered, yet the vlookup formula remains in the cell.  I have provided an example below:

**Step 1**. You have a lookuptable and a group of cell that use vlookup functions to display the table data.

[image]

**Step 2**.  In cell d3 a user enters: **/500**. The / triggers the Splat function which updates the lookup table with the new value for Jane (500) and replaces the lookup formula in cell d3.

[image]

**Step 3**.  After the Splat function fires, Jane has a 500 value in the table and cell d3 (via the lookup function) displays the updated value.

[image]

Ideally there would be some data validation built into the Splat function whereby the function would only fire with the / slash trigger and otherwise would through a data validation pop-up.

Any thoughts on how to approach this, sample code, articles, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I recently blogged on [something related](http://yoursumbuddy.com/prompt-to-add-new-items-to-combobox-or-data-validation/) that might help with parts of this.

Comment: Doug - Thanks I will definitely checkout your blog article.

Comment: You cannot do this with a Function in Excel. It has to be a Sub and called some other way (like a button macro or an event handler).

Comment: RBarry you don't think the Worksheet_Change event that David Z suggested can handle it?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Barry's comment describes my solution: a sub called from an event handler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, using the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Assume the workbook has a named range 'lookuptable' at G3:H6
    'Assume the workbook has a named range 'lookupColumn' at D3:D6

    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("lookupColumn")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not Left(Target, 1) = "/" Then Exit Sub

    UpdateLookupTable Target

End Sub

Sub UpdateLookupTable(cl As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim splatVal As String

    splatVal = Replace(cl.Value, "/", 0, , 1)
    r = Application.Match(cl.Offset(0, -1), Range("lookuptable").Columns(1), False)
    Range("lookuptable").Cells(r, 2).Value = splatVal
    cl.Value = splatVal

End Sub
```

I was not sure whether you intend to preserve the `VLOOKUP` formulas in Column D. This example does not, but it could be modified if you wanted to preserve these functions.

Comment: Thanks David.  I will give this a try.  I do need to preserve the formula in cell d3, but I might be able to figure that part out. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of `cl.Value = splatVal` change that line to `cl.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & cl.Offset(0,-1).Address & ",lookuptable,2,False)"`.

Comment: David - The spreadsheet does seem to recognize or respond when I input the data (i.e. /500).  Right now when I type /500 I simply enter a /500 into the cell.

Comment: You have to put this code in the appropriate `Worksheet` code module, otherwise it will not recognize the `_Change` event.

Comment: I believe I put it in the right place (the code module for the particular sheet that I'm working on, Yes?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done.  Let me give it another look, I've been known to make a typo here or there.

Comment: Okay  I was simply entering /500 and not hitting return.  Once I started hitting return it seem to fire.  Not quite working but I think I can figure it out.  I'll let you know how I make out.   Thankss again.

Comment: I don't think it can work unless you hit the return/enter key, otherwise, no change has occurred yet, so there's no way to trigger the event handler.  Macros don't run, dialogs won't open, and formulas won't re-calculate **while** you are actively editing a cell.

Comment: I believe I just about have it.  I'm just getting an error on this line of code: r = Application.Match(cl.Offset(0, -1), Range("lookuptable").Columns(1), False)  The error is Method range on object _Worksheet failed.

Comment: That error happens if you do **not** have a Named Range defining `lookuptable`.  You will need to use the Names Manager from the Formula ribbon, alternatively, replace "lookuptable" with "G3:H6".

Comment: I have the range. Does it have to be on the same sheet?

Comment: if it's not on the same sheet, we just need to qualify it fully, so change `Range("lookuptable")...` to `Worksheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Range("lookuptable")...`.  You'll have to make this change for both places where we reference this Range, make sure to revise so that it uses your worksheet's name.